# Ошибка при импорте таблиц в базу данных mysql(phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

При импорте базы размером в 1.5 гб, происходит ошибка

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/src/Lexer.php on line 488.

Это значит что скрипту в php не хватает времени на импорт. Хотя в php.ini я поставил время на 1000,  и размер возможно загружаемого файла увеличил до 2048 мб.

Можете сказать почему так происходит, может надо где то ещё сделать настройки? Или кто-то знает другие способы импорта больших файлов, сразу скажу что sypex dumper не работает, так как база - в gz архиве, а workbench не может подключится к mysql(xampp).

Comment: Я только через консоль импортирую большие файлы, через `use .. source...` обычно. но если файл в архиве то тут 2 вар-та- либо самому разархивировать, либо придется загружать файл на сервер и при импорте разархивировать его `gunzip < path/to/myfile.sql.gz | mysql -u user_name -p password db_name` где `path/to/myfile.sql.gz` - путь на сервере к архиву, `user_name, password` - имя пользователя и пароль юзера бд, `db_name` - имя базы в которую будет импорт происходить

Comment: А для localhost это будет работать?

Comment: можете поподробнее про импорт из под консоли описать.

Comment: Будет работать. надо через консоль зайти в папку с исполняемым mysql файлом (для того же xampp это xampp\mysql, наверное.. давно его не использова, не помню точно), и в консоли выполнить выше написанную команду. Или же, если дамп это .sql файл, то можно просто сперва зайти в mysql - `mysql -u user_name -p password`, потом создать базу (если импорт в новую) - `create database db_name;`, потом переключаемся на эту базу - `use db_name`, ну и дамп используем - `source /path/to/db.sql;`

Comment: положи в папку с phpmyadmin файл с phpinfo(); и посмотри, какой файл конфига отвечает за данный хост. скорее всего фиксил не тот файл.